# Process a large glossary?

Tags: compiling, glossaries, acronyms, memory

I have [a 1.1MB file with 20k acronyms (gene names)](http://www.tommycarstensen.com/genes.tex). I don't use all of the acronyms in my text, but I still get the error message below, when I try to compile. How can I avoid this?

```
(./tex/glossary.tex (./genes.tex
Runaway definition?
->,{A1BG},{A1CF},{A2M},{A2ML1},{A3GALT2},{A4GALT},{A4GNT},{AAAS},{AAC\ETC.
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
\glolist@acronym ...UFB2},{NDUFB3},{NDUFB4},{NDUFB
                                                  5},{NDUFB6},{NDUFB7},{NDUF...
l.10470 ...ssed, developmentally down-regulated 1}
```

Comment: For me it stops at `\newacronym{PIGK}{PIGK}{phosphatidylinositol glycan anchor biosynthesis class K}`, having some higher main memory size, but it takes very long to get there

Comment: Perhaps `bib2gls` is an option for you

Comment: You could perhaps use lualatex which uses dynamic memory allocation  but it's very big (my texlive 2017 version finally dies with `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [number of strings=494451].`, I would instead just get latex to write out which acronyms are used, then use perl to make a subset list of definitions to input.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle David, that's exactly the solution I had in mind. I wrote this quick and dirty command, but is there a better and cleaner way? `grep -h -o -i "acrfull{[a-zA-Z_]*}\|gls{[a-zA-Z_]*}" *.tex | cut -d"{" -f2 | cut -d"}" -f1 | sort -u`

Comment: @tommy.carstensen if you posted a test file it would be easier to suggest how to get there

Comment: if it works it works:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It works, but it's ugly :D I was just curious, because you wrote this: "I would instead just get latex to write out which acronyms are used"

Comment: @tommy.carstensen: Are you using `\gls` only?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Actually I would need `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` instead of `[a-zA-Z_]` and you are right, that I also miss out on `\glspl` and other things. I've decided just to identify the missing gene IDs in my `glossary.tex` and then copy them over from `genes.tex` manually.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen: I would rather split the huge file into more 'logical' files, e.g. a file containing some frequently used genes ...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer At first I didn't think it would be feasible to identify frequently used gene IDs, but actually it is! I am mostly interested in those in the GWAS catalog. I was able to narrow it down to 3,368 gene IDs by only taking into consideration gene IDs that are mentioned 3 or more times. This command is not entirely correct, but it does the job:

Comment: `join -t$'\t' <(curl -s https://www.ebi.ac.uk/gwas/api/search/downloads/alternative | cut -f15 | sort | uniq -c | awk '$1>=3{print $2}' | sort -u) <(curl -s ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/genenames/new/tsv/locus_groups/protein-coding_gene.txt | awk -F$'\t' 'NR>1{print $2"\t\\newacronym{"$2"}{"$2"}{"$3"}"}' | sort -t$'\t' -k1,1) | wc -l`. It should be piped to `cut -f2-` instead of `wc -l`. I was just doing a count...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick and (dirty) way (most likely I have reinvented some `glossaries` - wheel ;-)

The idea is following:

- Redefine `\gls` (and other similar macros), putting the used one into a list of used gls entries
- Store those values to a separate file, say `\jobname.used`
- Read in those values before `\loadglsentries` and redefine `\newacronym` to use only those entries that match the ones that have been stored, kick the other ones.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\LetLtxMacro\newacronymdefault\newacronym
\LetLtxMacro\glsorigdefault\gls

\newwrite\usedentries
\AtBeginDocument{
  \immediate\openout\usedentries=\jobname.used
}



\newif\ifshrinkglossaryentries

\shrinkglossaryentriestrue

\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcommand{\listofused}[1]{%
  \seq_gset_from_clist:Nn \gls_loaded_seq {#1}
}

\seq_new:N \gls_used_seq 
\seq_new:N \gls_loaded_seq

\ifshrinkglossaryentries

\RenewDocumentCommand{\newacronym}{O{}+m+m+m}{%
  \seq_if_in:NnT \gls_loaded_seq {#2} {%
    \newacronymdefault[#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}%
  }%
}
\fi
\ExplSyntaxOff

\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.used}{}{}


\loadglsentries{genes}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand{\gls}{+O{}+m}{%
  \glsorigdefault[#1]{#2}%
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \gls_used_seq {#2}
}  

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
  \immediate\write\usedentries{%
    \string\listofused{\seq_use:Nnnn \gls_used_seq { ,}{,}{}}
  }
  \immediate\closeout\usedentries
}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOff    


\begin{document}

\gls{PIGH}

\gls{ZZZ3}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh man, I feel so stupid, when you make it look so easy :D Thanks!!!

Comment: @tommy.carstensen: You're welcome. I'll try to improve it later on

Answer (score 1):

The [`glossaries` performance page](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-performance.shtml) compares the results of document builds for some files containing 1000 entry definitions, using a number of different methods provided by the base [`glossaries`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) package and the [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) extension package. In particular, check the [Alphabetical Order (Subset)](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-performance.shtml#subset) section. The files in these tests aren't as large as with your document, but it's possible to see which methods perform better for large datasets.

The best method for a large set of entries where only a subset is required in the document is to use `glossaries-extra` with [`bib2gls`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls). This has a considerable saving in resources as only those entries that are actually needed in the document require storage within TeX. (Naturally, `bib2gls` will need enough memory, but it's a Java application so it has better memory management than TeX.)

Comment: Thanks! I would probably have gone for `bib2gls`, if I had to do it again, instead of pruning the glossary of human gene IDs.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen You might be able to convert your `.tex` file to `.bib` format with `convertgls2bib`. (One drawback is that `bib2gls` is quite new, so there may be bugs that haven't been found yet.)